# Capistrano Deploy recipe to symlink Ruby on Rails folder public/images, not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Every time I upload images it goes to public/images/upload then when I run a cap deploy they get erased since it creates a new current directory.

How do I instruct Capistrano to move the files in public/images/upload to the shared/images/ then symlink those images to the current(new) release ?

```
after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:symlink_shared"
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"

    namespace :deploy do
      task :restart do
        run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
      end

      desc "Symlink shared configs and folders on each release."
      task :symlink_shared do
        run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/images/upload #{release_path}/public/images/uploads"
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have try to expand shared directory list?

```
#deploy.rb
set :shared_children, shared_children + %w{public/images/uploads}
```

**Edit** : Remove you code and set shared_children variable.
After that make a `cap deploy:setup` so that updated your shared dir.

Comment: So you want me to set that in the deploy.rb and keep everything else?

Comment: :shared_children is an array. Defaults values are %w(public/system log tmp/pids) We want to expand this list and add public/images/uploads to shared directory

Comment: Great! you can use this syntax so : `set :shared_children, %w{images/ public/images/uploads}`

Comment: `set :shared_children, shared_children + fetch(:upload_dirs)` gives me `undefined local variable or method `shared_children' for main:Object`. Was shared_children removed?

Comment: @GabrieleCirulli did you solve this problem? If so can you explain how [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21837690/how-do-i-symlink-my-product-images-in-production-on-a-capistrano-deploy)?

Comment: This was the cap2 way. Use: `set :linked_dirs, %w(public/images/uploads)`