# How do I symlink my product images in production on a Capistrano deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, symlink, spree

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391294/every-time-i-deploy-with-capistrano-two-images-are-removed-from-my-page) I received a solution to my problem that every time when I deploy my Spree Commerce app with Capistrano my images are removed (they are still there, but the folder names are wrong) and I have to add them again via admin.

Both on [this Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spree-user/bX3_1ln-q8M) and in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391294/every-time-i-deploy-with-capistrano-two-images-are-removed-from-my-page) to the question it is said that symlinking is solution.

> You need to make sure that your RAILS_ROOT/public/spree directory is
>   being symlinked in from the Capistrano shared directory and not
>   recreated every time you deploy. If this symlink isn't happening, your
>   images will be lost on every deploy.

I've tried a few things but I do not manage to symlink my images.

On the server they are in the folder /public/spree/products. What I tried is this:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :symlink_shared do
     run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/shared/spree/ #{release_path}/public/spree/""
  end
end
```

but this does not work. I do not know which shared path I have to enter. I hope someone can help me out or provide a link with explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Capistrano 3 you can use the same method I explained in the answer to my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098534/shared-children-not-working-in-capistrano-3).

In essence, `:shared_children` was how you'd do it in Capistrano 2, but it was removed in favor of `:linked_files` and `:linked_dirs`.

Just create your `public/spree/` directory in your repository, add it to `.gitignore` if you need to (it doesn't matter if they're tracked or not by Git), then edit your `deploy.rb` to use `:linked_dirs`:

```
set :linked_dirs, %w(public/spree)
```

This way, when Capistrano deploys it'll automatically create the directory in `shared/` and link it into your current release. Please keep in mind that if you need files to be present in that directory you have to copy them to `shared/` manually, using a tool like `rsync`. The same goes for files like `database.yml` (for which you'd use `:linked_files`).

Comment: Oh unfortunately it did not have the intended effect (I only copied the `set :linked_dirs %w(public/spree)` and the pages did not work anymore and even my logo changed back to spree_commerce one. I removed it but it still is not working. I should have copied some files first I guess.

Comment: The `public/spree` directory and its contents need to be in the `shared` directory on the server before you deploy!

Comment: I think you can just `rsync config/database.yml root@your-server.com:/var/www/my_rails_app/shared/config`